# Letter Connections

Tags: pattern, letter-sequence, connections-puzzle

What is the connection between each of these pairs and what is the missing letter?

A is to G

B is to P

D is to Q

F is to T

C is to ?

Good luck!

Comment: See short discussion [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56115619#56115619) for why [word-property] was edited out. The remaining tags should cover the puzzle sufficiently.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think that C is to

> C

Reasoning

> If we write all the letters in lower case the connection becomes more obvious.
>  **a** is to **g**.
>  **b** is to **p**.
>  **d** is to **q**.
>  **f** is to **t**.
>  and we see that each letter is obtained from the other (with a little imagination) by reflecting in the horizontal axis. Under this transformation, the letter **c** just maps onto itself.